# application does not retain state of objects on orientation change

Tags: java, android

I have got this application that displays a resistor(compound image) and below it are four number pickers that for the user to pick the values...everything works fine until orientation is changed, and the user interface is not re-created as i would expect retaining all the displayed values of number pickers and image views...what am i getting wrong in my save method??

Here is my Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    TextView resistorValue;
    MyImageView bandOne, bandTwo, bandThree, tolerance;
    int figureOne;
    int figureTwo;
    int multiplier;
    String toleranceRate;
    String resistanceDisplayed;
    MyNumberPicker pickerOne;
    MyNumberPicker pickerTwo;
    MyNumberPicker pickerThree;
    MyNumberPicker pickerTolerance;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String colorSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //gets shared preferences
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        //initialize the user interface objects
        rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        bandOne = (MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorOne);
        bandTwo = (MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorTwo);
        bandThree = (MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorThree);
        tolerance = (MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.Tolerance);
        resistorValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resValue);

        pickerOne = (MyNumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.bandOne);
        pickerTwo = (MyNumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.bandTwo);
        pickerThree = (MyNumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.bandThree);
        pickerTolerance = (MyNumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.bandTolerance);

        //checks for shared preferences 
        colorSelected = prefs.getString("background_color", "WHITE");
        if(colorSelected.equals("RED")){
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }else if(colorSelected.equals("GREEN")){
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }else if(colorSelected.equals("BLUE")){
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }else if(colorSelected.equals("BLACK")){
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }else{
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            bandOne = (MyImageView)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bandOne");
            bandTwo = (MyImageView)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bandTwo");
            bandThree = (MyImageView)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bandThree");
            tolerance = (MyImageView)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("tolerance");
            pickerOne = (MyNumberPicker)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("pickerOne");
            pickerTwo = (MyNumberPicker)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("pickerTwo");
            pickerThree = (MyNumberPicker)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("pickerThree");

        }

        pickerOne.setMinValue(0);
        pickerOne.setMaxValue(9);
        pickerTwo.setMinValue(0);
        pickerTwo.setMaxValue(9);
        pickerThree.setMinValue(0);
        pickerThree.setMaxValue(9);
        pickerTolerance.setMinValue(0);
        pickerTolerance.setMaxValue(3);

        //sets the displayed values of the number pickers
        pickerOne.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Black", "Brown", "Red",
                "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Grey",
                "White" });
        pickerTwo.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Black", "Brown", "Red",
                "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Grey",
                "White" });
        pickerThree.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Black", "Brown", "Red",
                "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Grey",
                "White" });

        pickerTolerance.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "Brown", "Red", "Gold", "Silver"});

        //triggered when numberPickers value are changed
        pickerOne.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                switch (newVal) {
                case 0:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                    bandOne.setTag(Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.black));
                    figureOne = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    bandOne.setTag(Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.brown));
                    figureOne = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    figureOne = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
                    figureOne = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                    figureOne = 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                    figureOne = 5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    figureOne = 6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.violet);
                    figureOne = 7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    figureOne = 8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    bandOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
                    figureOne = 9;
                    break;
                }
                calculateResistorValue();
            }
        });

        pickerTwo.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                switch (newVal) {
                case 0:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                    figureTwo = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    figureTwo = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    figureTwo = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
                    figureTwo = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                    figureTwo = 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                    figureTwo = 5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    figureTwo = 6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.violet);
                    figureTwo = 7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    figureTwo = 8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    bandTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
                    figureTwo = 9;
                    break;
                }
                calculateResistorValue();
            }
        });

        pickerThree.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                switch (newVal) {
                case 0:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                    multiplier = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    multiplier = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    multiplier = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
                    multiplier = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                    multiplier = 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
                    multiplier = 5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    multiplier = 6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.violet);
                    multiplier = 7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    multiplier = 8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    bandThree.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
                    multiplier = 9;
                    break;
                }
                calculateResistorValue();
            }
        });

        pickerTolerance.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){
                switch(newVal){
                case 0:
                    tolerance.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    toleranceRate = "1%";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tolerance.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    toleranceRate = "2%";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tolerance.setImageResource(R.drawable.gold);
                    toleranceRate = "5%";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tolerance.setImageResource(R.drawable.silver);
                    toleranceRate = "10%";
                    break;  
                }
                calculateResistorValue();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.preferences_background_color) {
            CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"red","green", "blue", "black"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
            builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                //opens a dialog that let the user choose the background color and saves it to shared preferences
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    switch(which){
                    case 0:
                        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        colorSelected="RED";
                        editor.putString("background_color", colorSelected);
                        editor.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        colorSelected="GREEN";
                        editor.putString("background_color", colorSelected);
                        editor.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        colorSelected="BLUE";
                        editor.putString("background_color", colorSelected);
                        editor.commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        colorSelected="BLACK";
                        editor.putString("background_color", colorSelected);
                        editor.commit();
                        break;
                    default:
                        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("bandOne", bandOne);
        outState.putSerializable("bandTwo", bandTwo);
        outState.putSerializable("bandThree", bandThree);
        outState.putSerializable("tolerance", tolerance);
        outState.putSerializable("pickerOne", pickerOne);
        outState.putSerializable("pickerTwo", pickerTwo);
        outState.putSerializable("pickerThree", pickerThree);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    //calculates the resistor value and sets text of textView
    public void calculateResistorValue(){

        double resValue = ((10 * figureOne) + figureTwo) * Math.pow(10, multiplier) / 1000;
        String resMessage = null;
        if(resValue >= (10^6)){
            resValue /= (10^6);
            resMessage= Integer.toString((int) resValue) + "  M Ohms";
        }else if(resValue >= (10^3)){
            resValue /= (10^3);
            resMessage = Integer.toString((int) resValue) + "  k Ohms";
        }else{
            resMessage = Integer.toString((int) resValue) + "  Ohms";
        }
        resistorValue.setText(resMessage + "  " + toleranceRate );
    }       
}
```

Also I have got custom classes My Number Picker and My Image View (and they work correctly) with XML file as well, i believe the mistake is in my save method or in On Create method once objects are being deserialized.

![resistor picture] http://www.electronics123.com/page/calculate-resistor-values

Comment: You can't store anything extending from `View` in `onSaveInstanceState()` - when you're rotated your entire Activity and all Views get destroyed. What are you actually trying to save?

Comment: i am trying to save the way the user interface looks, the image resources for the image views are selected according to a switch case in the onChangeValueListener... how can i save those selected values on orientation change

Comment: so basically i'm trying to save the state of all the views like NumberPicker and ImageView objects

Comment: Views automatically restore their own state on rotation as long as they have an `id`, which your's all seem to have. Is there some other state you want saved that isn't just one of the standard things an `ImageView`, etc. already have?

Comment: so basically my ImageView has got 9 different drawable that can be displayed...the drawable (which are all the same apart from a small colored band that changes color) is selected when the number picker value is changed...so let's say the default source for the first ImageView is the drawable with the black band....then i change value of the number picker and the image is changed to the one with the red band...but on orientation change the black band comes back and instead i need the red band to still be there....why does this happen??

Comment: Probably because you're doing crazy stuff with saving the wrong things and causing a giant memory leak. What happens if you remove your saving code altogether?

Comment: Also i added a link to a picture of what my layout of ImageView objects looks like hoping to make it easier for you to understand...i know i can be a bit confusing when explaining my problems sorry

Comment: i removed everything now...and just left the code that calls the superclass method

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save too much data into the bundle. Only save what you need, perhaps store the values of the NumberPicker changes into members on the main activity class, then use those members to save the data. You can move logic in the NumberPicker.OnValueChangedListener to a common function, and call this function onCreate when you have your activity instance after the orientation change. You will only be loading simple primitive values from the bundle, instead of complex view objects.

*edit* whoops you are using a member already, just make a function and save/load those values from the bundle and call the function to restore the number pickers!

Comment: i don't really get what you mean could you give me a code example please??how can i save the imageResource of an ImageView object into a variable...not sure you can do that if the image is selected dinamically

Comment: i also don't understand why this is not done automatically for me as onSavedInstanceState is supposed to be saving the state of all my View objects(ImageView and NumberPicker) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try just save the values:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("figureOne", pickerOne);
        outState.putInt("figureTwo", pickerTwo);
        outState.putInt("multiplier", multiplier);
        outState.putInt("tolerance", pickerTolerance.getValue());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

In the onCreate(), have the code to restore values after all the listeners setted. The code to restore values like this:

```
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            pickerOne.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt("figureOne"));
            pickerTwo.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt("figureTwo"));
            pickerThree.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt("multiplier");
            pickerTolerance.setValue(savedInstanceState.getInt("tolerance"));
        }
```